# Django Form Imagefield validation for certain width and height

Tags: django, height, width, imagefield

I am trying to validate the image dimension in form level and display a message to user if submitted photo does not meet requirement which is image dimension 1080x1920. I dont want to store the width and height size in database. I tried with the Imagefield width and height attribute. But it is not working.

```
class Adv(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=r'photos/%Y/%m/',
        width_field = ?,
        height_field = ?,
        help_text='Image size: Width=1080 pixel. Height=1920 pixel',
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in two ways

1. Validation in model

   from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

   ```
   def validate_image(image):
       max_height = 1920
       max_width = 1080
       height = image.file.height 
       width = image.file.width
       if width > max_width or height > max_height:
           raise ValidationError("Height or Width is larger than what is allowed")

   class Photo(models.Model):
       image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to=image_upload_path, validators=[validate_image])
   ```
2. Cleaning in forms

   ```
           def clean_image(self):
               image = self.cleaned_data.get('image', False)
               if image:
                   if image._height > 1920 or image._width > 1080:
                       raise ValidationError("Height or Width is larger than what is allowed")
                   return image
               else:
                   raise ValidationError("No image found")
   ```

Comment: I am looking solution to display the message in field (e.g. if email is not in correct form then you see the message that "email is not valid. please provide valid email'' i want this type of message displayed if the uploaded photo does not fulfill requirement.

Comment: you can change the message inside ValidationError

Comment: Tried first way: _Validation in model_ and got **django 'File' object has no attribute 'height**' error. In order to get it work remove the file part from assignments as folllowing:
`height = image.height` and `width = image.width`.

Answer (score 1):

We need an image processing library such as PI to detect image dimension, here is the proper solution:

```
# Custom validator to validate the maximum size of images
def maximum_size(width=None, height=None):
    from PIL import Image

    def validator(image):
        img = Image.open(image)
        fw, fh = img.size
        if fw > width or fh > height:
            raise ValidationError(
            "Height or Width is larger than what is allowed")
     return validator
```

then in the model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to=image_upload_path, validators=[maximum_size(128,128)])
```